# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'

Tags: python

Я просмотрел все форумы и даже тут. Но никакое решение не помогло мне. Я переустанавливал pyTelegramBotAPI, просмотрел нет ли в списке библиотек telebot. Мне программа выдаёт такую ошибку ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'. Хотя у других людей при написании import telebot нет проблем.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: это очень популярная ошибка импорта, приложите более конкретное описание, что вы делаете. Дать корректный ответ, без попытки угадать, будет сложно. Чтобы исправить вопрос нажмите [edit] под самим вопросом

Comment: Почитайте про окружения. Студия просто видит не тот питон, в который вы ставили телебот.

Comment: я попробовал удалить расширение питона в visual studio( но через консоль установлен питон), и программа перестала выдавать ошибку на telebot. Однако запустив, мне говорят, что нужно расширение установить, сделав это вылезает ошибка с telebot. Замкнутый круг прямо....

Comment: Где-то в студии можно выбирать/переключать окружение питона. Нужно там выбрать правильное окружение.

Comment: как мне понять какое окружение мне нужно?

Comment: @IDude проще всего - создать новое, и установить в него все что вам нужно.

Comment: я уже смирился и написал эту прогу в pycharm, и там такая же ошибка(

Answer (score 0):

Найдите в папке проекта папку с виртуальной средой (к примеру это папка venv). Активируйте ее командой: `source venv/bin/activate`. Где venv возможное название папки (измените в команде venv на название папки если оно отличается). Установите библиотеку: `pip3 install telebot`.

Если данной папки нет создайте: `python3 -m venv venv`. Далее выполните команды указанные выше.

Используйте в своем проекте данную папку с виртуальным окружением и установленной в него библиотекой telebot.